# Does the set of irreps of a compact Lie group carry an algebraic structure?

Tags: fourier-analysis, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, convolution

**Question:**  If $G$ is a compact Lie group, does the set of equivalence classes of unitary complex irreps $\widehat{G}$ carry an algebraic structure such as a natural binary operation or perhaps even a monoidal structure?

**Motivation:**  If $G$ was the abelian compact Lie group $S^1$, we would have the first convolution theorem: $\widehat{f \ast g}(n) = \hat{f}(n) \hat{g}(n)$ and also the second convolution theorem: $\widehat{f g}(n) = (\hat{f} \ast \hat{g})(n)$.

In the case of $G$ non-abelian, the first theorem makes sense to generalize since I can convolve over any group and multiply functions pointwise over any set.  However, the second convolution theorem does not immediately seem to be generalizable since $\widehat{G}$ is not a group in general--unless $\widehat{G}$ still carries some other kind of monoidal structure or perhaps some even weaker algebraic structure so that convolution still makes sense. (And I really WANT there to be a generalization because I am working with a fourier transform of a product of functions over $SO(3)$!)

Thanks! :)

Comment: Are you looking for the representation ring, as in this classical paper be G. Segal: http://www.numdam.org/article/PMIHES_1968__34__113_0.pdf ?

Comment: Formally speaking the representation (semi)ring doesn't address the question... indeed the representation ring, as an abelian group, is just the free abelian group over this set. Nevertheless introducing this ring is a good substitute; what would extend the product from the abelian case is the underlying product of this ring. The main difference with the abelian case is that the tensor product of two irreps is not an irrep.

Comment: @YCor How would the fourier "coefficients" of non-irreducible representations be defined?

Comment: You'll find some context here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_character_formula

Comment: @YCor I don't immediately see how that answers my question.